# pkg-config package not working on debian virtualbox environement

Tags: shell

I am running Debian 8 on a Virtual box environment. The problem I am facing is the use of the `pkg-config` package when compiling a c++ file.

[image]

When I run the first command I get errors but when the I try to compile vision.cpp with the output of the second command it works perfectly as seen below.

[image]

I would be grateful if you guys could help me figure this out. And yes, I triple checked I used back-ticks (to the left of the 1 on the macbook pro) just so I don't look like an idiot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because I was using fish terminal which uses parenthesis instead of backticks to run subcommands. Another problem is that fish does not separate by spaces but pkg-config does therefore the correct command is:

`eval g++ -o code code.cc (pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)`

I used this link as a reference: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/982